# QGIS 3.4 (mac) std::bad_alloc error

Tags: raster, vector

I get the above error when trying to add a new raster or vector layer. Does anyone know how to correct it as the resulting projection is nowhere near where I need it.

Comment: Have seen this error when dealing with raster files too, haven't been able to replicate/figure it out. Any consistency to the one you're seeing?

Comment: I got this error opening a project with many layers, after updating to QGIS 3.10 Coruña. The project had worked fine in QGIS 3.4.